# Realtime Push Popup window for website

Tags: plugin, extensions, jquery, javascript, ajax

Is there a way to trigger a popup on an end users browser in real time, not just when page loads,  sort of like a live push notification but instead a popup window (modal) opens up on the end users end with whatever content I have populated (i.e. survey, video, etc).  My site has live webinars so there is an audience there at all times, but I want to push them changing content in thepop up windows as necessary.

Comment: You should check the JED for possible solutions,  this site is for Joomla develoment and setup questions.  Once you've done some research, we'd be happy to help with specific questions.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Comment: A Joomla website?

Comment: The JED is the Joomla Extensions Directory at  http://extensions.joomla.org/.  Look there for solutions, look here for questions about using on your Joomla website. :)

Comment: I already looked on the JED, I didn't see a solution that does push method pop ups, hence I figured it needs to be developed.  So I posted the question here figuring someone may have done something similar before.

Answer (score 2):

- In Joomla, there is a similar concept called **keepalive**.

**JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive')** - Keep session alive, for example, while editing or creating an article.

It works simply calling to the site to keep session cookie alive. You can check how it is generated here: libraries/cms/html/behavior.php, function keepalive().

- Alternatively, you can find a plugin for the same feature in JED:  **KeepaliveLight** http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/session-management/19814

In your case, instead of simply calling the index.php page, you have to check if there is webinar going on, and show a message in the site.